# After installing the realtek driver, wired connected ui not showing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, realtek

I'm Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS & kernel version is using 6.2.0-26-generic. I'm now having a problem with ui not showing after installing that driver(2.5G/5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 6.4).

[image]

The image in question is as follows.

[image]

The wired LAN is still in the UNCLAMED state.

[image]

[image]

I've tried many different methods, but I only have one yaml file. I found a lot of similar problems but couldn't find them exactly the same as me. I think there is a problem with the yaml file, and also does not existing 00-installer-config.yaml  Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one possible answer from here [Original Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed). I hope it resolves your issue.

The package that provides network drivers, among many others, is linux-modules-extra. For reasons we don’t understand, it didn’t get installed in your update.

The package is here [Ubuntu Generic Package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kernel/linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic)

Please download it on some other computer and transfer it with a USB key or similar. Drag and drop it to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer.

Now, in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

**Reboot**. Your network devices should now be working.

**CAUTION:** Note to searchers: It is doubtful that your exact kernel version and, therefore, linux-modules-extra version is still 6.2.0-26-generic as above. Please verify your running kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

If, as an example, you find that your running kernel version is 6.2.0-26-generic, then that is the version of linux-modules-extra that you need, i.e. linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic.